# How to remove ellipsis in a dropdown to show the full text?

Tags: css, wordpress, web, menu, dropdown

So if you go to this website - https://community.entermedschool.com/ and on the primary menu bar, hover to Forums -> General Discussion and you can see that it doesn't show the full text. It shows it like this:

[image]

I want to show the text fully so I want to remove the ellipsis and show the text in that place. I've tried to add this bit of code in the custom css section but it hasn't done anything.

```
#primary-navbar{
    white-space:nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add to the css class of the ul "sub-menu":

```
         .sub-menu
         {
          width: fit-content;
         }
```

It will solve your problem. The problem is the container's width is not enough for the text to space out.